# how does |> pipe operator in elixir work?

Tags: elixir

is this all similar to using `|` operator on unix? As per the [doc](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2) it is about passing first argument to the function, so would like to know what is the big deal here about this operator compared to traditional way of passing first argument in any functional language like in Pascal or C.

Also, can we pass variable argument using this way?

Comment: You should also consider what is getting "piped": a list, a stream or a flow.  They are all possible in Elxir and it is important to know those different concepts. See http://elixir-lang.org/blog/2016/07/14/announcing-genstage/

Comment: There's a good basic discussion of the idea here: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html#the-pipe-operator

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The main benefit of the pipe operator is that instead of calling multiple functions in a nested fashion

```
Enum.join(Enum.map(String.split("hello, world!", " "), &String.capitalize/1), " ")
```

or having many intermediate "throw-away variables"

```
string = "hello, world!"
words = String.split(string, " ")
capitalized_words = Enum.map(words, &String.capitalize/1)
Enum.join(capitalized_words, " ")
```

you can use the pipe operator to write

```
"hello, world!"
|> String.split(" ")
|> Enum.map(&String.capitalize/1)
|> Enum.join
```

Most notably, arguments are now very close to the function that receives them. Moreover, the order of the function invocations in the code resembles the order of executions - read from top to bottom instead from the inside out. Finally, not having the unnecessary "throw-away variables" reduces noise.

Not only does it make your code easier to read, it also tends to positively influence how you design your APIs. It encourages you to think about your code as a series of transformations on data, which leads to very clean solutions in many cases.

> Also, can we pass variable argument using this way?

No, you cannot pass multiple arguments in this way - although you could use a tuple for example, to pass multiple values via a single argument.

Answer (score 4):

> is this all similar to using `|` operator on unix?

Not exactly. Consider the following example:

```
echo 'foo' | echo 'bar'
#⇒ bar
```

With an Elixir pipe operator, we were to get `foo bar` string printed out.

If you want the comparison against unix pipe, it’s more like `| xargs`, save for `xargs` will *append* the standard input to the command given (*append* the output of the previous command, when used after pipe,) while Elixir pipe operator will *prepend* the output of the previous command.

> what is the big deal here about this operator compared to traditional way of passing first argument

Well, it’s a matter of maintaining readable code. Consider the following task: one should receive parameters from the standard input, validate them, possibly coerce them to the respective types and then perform an action, providing these arguments as an input. In Elixir we’d write this using pipe operator:

```
input
|> validate(ValidatorEngine)
|> coerce(to: [:int, :float])
|> perform
```

Without this operator, the exactly same code would look like:

```
perform(coerce(validate(input, ValidatorEngine), to: [:int, :float]))
```

What is more readable, maintainable and, after all, elegant?

> in any functional language like in Pascal or C

Neither `Pascal` nor `C` are *functional*. These languages are *imperative*. Those two are related as “*having fun*” compared to “*having functions*”.

> can we pass variable argument using this way?

It’s easy to check in Elixir codebase: [`Macro.unpipe`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.4.0/lib/elixir/lib/macro.ex#L134) that unpipes the `foo |> bar |> baz` notation has no magic inside. Hence, no, one can not just pipe as many arguments as they wanted. Whenever it’s needed, one uses tuples/lists/maps structures to wrap the output of the previous command to the single term.

Comment: Not to split semantic hairs but C and Pascal may be _procedural_ but I think the term you're looking for is _imperative_.  Procedural is not the opposite of functional--imperative is.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci yes and no, thanks for the tip. I wanted to explicitly express a difference between functions and procedures, but since I am not a native speaker it seems I did not succeed :) Will fix.