# Loop through a list of values, find matches in keys and sum matched values in Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I'm learning Elixir and I'm having a difficulty with this simple problem:

I have a list of values:

`my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "y", "z", "a", "e"]`

And I have a map:

`my_map = %{"a" => -1, "b" => 0, "c" => 1, "d" => 2, "e" => 3}`

I want to loop through `my_list`, find all *key* occurrences in `my_map` and sum the values from `my_map` if the occurrence happened.

In the above example it should return 2 because:

`-1 + 0 + 1 + (ignored) + (ignored) - 1 + 3`

`# => 2`

This is a very easy thing to do in languages with mutable variables (we can loop the list and add a counter). I'm working on changing my mindset.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Have a look at [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.3/Enum.html#reduce/3) and [Map.get/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.3/Map.html#get/3). These functions should be all you need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm working on changing my mindset.

Admirable. You'll find great success in Elixir if you're willing to change your mindset and try to think more functionally. With that in mind, let's break the problem down.

> I want to loop through `my_list`

More precisely, you want to do something to each element of the list and get a list of the results. That's [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#map/2).

```
Enum.map(my_list, fn x -> ...)
```

Now, `...` needs to be replaced with what we want to *do* to each list element. We want to get the corresponding map elements, ignoring those that are not present. Since we're taking a sum, "ignoring" really just means "replacing with zero". [`Map.get/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Map.html#get/3) can get a value from a map, using a default if not provided.

```
Enum.map(my_list, fn x -> Map.get(my_map, x, 0) end)
```

Now, we have a list of numbers. We just want the sum. That could be done in terms of [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#reduce/3), but summing is a common enough task that it has its own function: [`Enum.sum/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#sum/1).

```
Enum.sum(Enum.map(my_list, fn x -> Map.get(my_map, x, 0) end))
```

Finally, this reads backwards. It says "sum the result of mapping over the list", when it would read much cleaner as "take the list, get the elements from the map, then take a sum". We can clean it up with the [pipe operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584737/how-does-pipe-operator-in-elixir-work). The following is equivalent to the above.

```
my_list |> Enum.map(fn x -> Map.get(my_map, x, 0) end) |> Enum.sum
```

Comment: While this answer offers great readability, it should be pointed out that it would be highly inefficient because would need to build an expensive intermediate list (I recently [benchmarked](https://github.com/sabiwara/iter/blob/main/benchmarks/map_sum.exs) these and the differences are [quite important](https://github.com/sabiwara/iter/blob/main/benchmarks/map_sum.results.txt)). Other answers like reduce or recursion should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice use case for a [comprehension](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1):

```elixir
for key <- my_list, val = my_map[key], reduce: 0 do
  acc -> acc + val
end
```

Here the `val = my_map[key]` is a filter. When `key` is not in `my_map`, the result will be `nil`, which is a falsy value so is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

While both answers given here are perfectly valid, I’m to post another one using plain recursion, for the sake of completeness.

```elixir
defmodule Summer do
  def consume(list, map, acc \\ 0) # head

  def consume([], _, acc), do: acc # exhausted
  def consume([h | t], map, acc) when is_map_key(map, h),
    do: consume(t, map, acc + Map.fetch!(map, h))
  def consume([_h | t], map, acc), do: consume(t, map, acc)
end

Summer.consume my_list, my_map
#⇒ 2
```